# Авторизация и последующий парсинг страниц после нее

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

При попытке авторизации на сайте, отправляю POST запрос и сохраняю полученный ответ в html странице:

```
session = requests.Session()

response = session.post(link, data=data, headers = HEADERS)
with open ("test.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

Открывая сохраненный файл через браузер, получаю главную страницу сайта с пройденной авторизацией

Но далее, отправляя GET запрос на другую страницу (по сути являясь уже авторизованным через сессию), и сохраняя таким же способом ответ, получаю результатом заново редирект на страницу авторизации

```
check_response = session.get(url, headers = HEADERS, params = None)
with open ("check.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as c:
    c.write(check_response.text)
```

Соответственно, не могу спарсить ничего из нужных мне страниц после авторизации через BeautifulSoup

В чем может быть причина такого поведения?

Comment: Проверьте что куки приходят в ответе при POST и что они отправляются при последующем GET. Это можно увидеть, если включите логирование: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/39e6090e6a41c7ebe5982c027ffd7a248e858fa8/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L23

Comment: Кст, заголовки HTTP можно у самой сессии установить: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/manual_auth_to_github.py#L16 или https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/html_parsing/yummyanime_club__anime_updates.py#L37. И мб проблема в том, что вы устанавливаете заголовки, а куки в них тоже передаются и мб это переписывает их (хотя по-моему, такое не должно было случиться)

Comment: попробовал установить заголовки в сессии - работает, по сути, и так и так. проблема, видимо, не в этом.
При простом запросе на куки через response.cookies пост запрос их показывает, а вот get запрос возвращает ошибку AttributeError - у строки нет метода cookies. Точно также как и url, history и тд.
видимо проблема кроется в типе данных, но знаний пока не хватает, чтобы понять

Comment: Попробуйте делать как в браузере. Заходим на страницу session.get, регистрируемся session.post и заходим на страницу session.get. headers в session внитрите

Comment: решил проблему с AttributeError, в итоге get запрос на куки возвращает пустой список. <RequestsCookieJar[]>